# Get the current table within the for loop

Tags: office-scripts

This code:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('MySheet');
    let tables = sheet.getTables();
    let rowCount = 0;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        rowCount = sheet.getTable[i].getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRowCount();
        console.log(rowCount);
    };
}
```

Is returning the error:

```
Line 7: sheet.getTable[i] is undefined
```

How do I express: get the current table within the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, `getTable` is a method that accepts the name of the table.  Passing in the index doesn't work.

You can always do it this way ...

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('MySheet');
    let tables = sheet.getTables();
    let rowCount = 0;

    tables.forEach((table) => {
        rowCount = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRowCount();
        console.log(rowCount);
    });
}
```

... or use the index of the `tables` variable that you already defined ...

```
rowCount = tables[i].getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRowCount();
```